# Обособление оборота "лучше, чем кто-либо"

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

1) Правильно обособлен оборот в следующих предложениях?

(1) Лучше,  **чем кто-либо**,  он понимал это.

(2) Лучше, **чем кто-либо еще (другой)**, он понимал это.

(3) Он понимал это лучше,  **чем кто-либо.**

2) **Зависит ли обособление** от распространенности оборота и его позиции или оборот всегда обособляется по формальному правилу?

3) **В этих примерах необособленный оборот — это ошибка?**

**Лучше чем кто-либо** он понимал, как бывает страшна толпа, и понимал: случись что, и его три десятка, даже вместе с конниками маркиза, сомнут в миг.

Когда же мы спросили о масонах, а о них она знает все **лучше чем кто-либо**, она поинтересовалась, уж не собираются ли все тут заночевать, ибо она может говорить о масонах часами. [Василий Катанян. Прикосновение к идолам (1998)

Дмитрий Шляхтин заявил РИА Новости, что **лучше чем кто-либо другой** понимал, что у российских ходоков могут возникнуть проблемы...

Answer (score 1):

Необособленный оборот - ошибка! И не играет, сколь он распространён.

Срисовываю с ответа Справки Грамоты.ру:

> Запятая поставлена правильно: здесь обычный сравнительный оборот.
>   ***Запятая не ставится внутри сочетаний (не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем и т. п., если они не
>   содержат сравнения***: *Посылка весит не больше чем восемь
>   килограммов* (ср.: ...не больше восьми килограммов).

И вдругорядь подтверждает свою позицию, но с вариациями, но теперь я уже процитирую с вопросом.

[Вопрос № 213142](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

> Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста (совсем запуталась), когда
>   ставится запятая перед словом ЧЕМ? "более, чем половина; лучше, чем ты
>   думаешь; не позднее, чем за 10 дней; не ранее, чем через 10 дней и не
>   позднее, чем через месяц..." Никак не могу систематизировать... знаю,
>   что иногда не ставится... Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Запятая не ставится внутри сочетаний *(не) больше чем, (не) меньше
>   чем, (не) раньше чем* и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения: *Выпуск
>   продукции увеличился больше чем вдвое*. Но при наличии сравнения или
>   сопоставления корректно выделение этих сочетаний: *Он вернется не
>   позже, чем этого потребуют обстоятельства*.
>
> ---

См. также [ЛУЧШЕ+ЧЕМ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо.  Но вот что меня смущает: почему это наши грамматики не приводят примеров с неопределенными наречиями. В этом случае сравнение какое-то неполноценное, неконкретное, да и произносится сочетание в одну фразу, особенно если нераспространенное.   А нельзя ли нам в устойчивые обороты записаться?   "Лучше чем кто-либо" - это значит  "лучше других".

Comment: Ааа! Больше-меньше-раньше-позже - и никакого итэпэ! На вопрос "почему" наука ответа не даёт.